# C# ASP.NET FindControl keeps returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I have a `TextBox` and a `Button` in my webpage. The user enters a number in the `TextBox` and clicks the `Button`, which creates (n+1) `TextBox`es in a `Panel`.

As you can see in the code, I have assigned `ID`s to the `TextBox` instances , again when trying to access the `TextBox` instances using `FindControl()` , I keep getting a `NullReferenceException` for **ONLY** the last `TextBox` (ID : f1) , what am I doing wrong here ?

Initially `Button1.Text` is not `"Find"`.

Code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Button1.Text.Equals("Find"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("Number" + i);
            n[i] = Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text);
        }
        localhost.Search s = new localhost.Search();
        resultLabel = new Label();
        TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("f1");
        int fNumber = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);            // tb1 is null
        if (s.LinearSearch(n, fNumber))
            resultLabel.Text = "FOUND!";
        else
            resultLabel.Text = "NOT FOUND!";
        form1.Controls.Add(resultLabel);
    }
    else
    {
        size = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        n = new int[size];
        TextBox1.Enabled = false;
        boxes = new TextBox[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Text = "Number " + (i + 1) + " : ";
            boxes[i] = new TextBox();
            boxes[i].ID = "Number" + i;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(l);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(boxes[i]);
        }
        Label l1 = new Label();
        l1.Text = "Find Number : ";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(l1);
        findBox = new TextBox();
        findBox.ID = "f1";
        Debug.Write("[!D] ID : "+findBox.ID);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(findBox);
        Button1.Text = "Find";
    }
}
```

ASPX code for the page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        How Many Numbers&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="OK" />
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you re-create the dynamically generated textboxes on post back?

Comment: @Mr.香港人 : I'm sorry, I don't know what that means as I am new to c# and ASP.NET.

Comment: I just modified your code a bit for debugging, but was unable to reproduce your issue, instead, I even can't get the first textbox, here's the link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/11RDQx Did I miss something??

Comment: @Mr.香港人 please refer this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r339uA

Comment: Still unable to reproduce.. are you sure you can receive ALL textboxes except the last one on Button1_Click event..? you have to re-create the textboxes on Post back or else all textbox will lose..

Comment: @Mr.香港人: Yes, I am sure. The `TextBox` with ID `f1` is the only one that fails.

Comment: Try adding Panel1.FindControl("f1").GetType(); what's the type of f1??

Comment: Something wrong with the code. You are looping in codebehind that means you are expecting multiple controls while aspx mark up shows only one text box. Please explain scenario of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Mr.香港人 : `Debug.Write("[D!] "+Panel1.FindControl("f1").GetType());` , unable to execute as I am getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: That means Control "f1" wasn't in Panel1... Try printing out the control names in Panel1..

Comment: @Amit : Initially I have a textbox and a button, I am trying to get a number 'n' as input and upon click of the button, add 'n+1' textboxes dynamically to the panel. All the textboxes are getting added and when I am trying to get their values, I am able to retrieve the values of all the textboxes except the last one with ID f1, where I am getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenver you are creating dynamic controls you need to recreate it on postback. Hope this helps

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateControls();
        if (Button1.Text.Equals("Find"))
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                 TextBox tb = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("Number" + i);
                 n[i] = Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text);
            }
           localhost.Search s = new localhost.Search();
           resultLabel = new Label();
           TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("f1");
           int fNumber = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);            // tb1 is null
         if (s.LinearSearch(n, fNumber))
           resultLabel.Text = "FOUND!";
        else
          resultLabel.Text = "NOT FOUND!";
        form1.Controls.Add(resultLabel);
       }
        else
        {
            Button1.Text = "Find";
        }


    }

    protected void CreateControls()
    {
        var size = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        var n = new int[size];
            TextBox1.Enabled = false;
            var boxes = new TextBox[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Label l = new Label();
                l.Text = "Number " + (i + 1) + " : ";
                boxes[i] = new TextBox();
                boxes[i].ID = "Number" + i;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(l);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(boxes[i]);
            }
            Label l1 = new Label();
            l1.Text = "Find Number : ";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(l1);
            var findBox = new TextBox();
            findBox.ID = "f1";
            Debug.Write("[!D] ID : " + findBox.ID);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(findBox);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the whole page for ID `f1` rather than searching in a panel.

```
TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)FindControl("f1");
```

Add the ID in your textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="f1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In your aspx page there is nothing with f1 ID because of which you were getting the null reference exception when trying to get the element's Text.

Comment: Tried it, but still getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: _In your aspx page there is nothing with f1 ID_ , but I have this `findBox.ID = "f1";` in the else part,

Comment: But u r facing error in if part and the cause for your problem is that there is nothing with ID f1